# How can I "click" all divs in the firebug console?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I perform a "click" action on all the rows that start with "user_" in the following html:

```
<div id="rows">
  <div id="user_1"></div>
  <div id="user_2"></div>
  <div id="user_3"></div>
  <div id="user_4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does Firebug have to do with the question?

Comment: I'm looking to perform the action the firebug JS console

Comment: The answer is the same whether or not you use the console, so I'll just go ahead and remove the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming by "perform a click action" you mean "trigger the click event", you can use an [attribute starts-with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector, and the [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) method with no arguments (equivalent to `trigger("click")`):

```
$("div[id^='user_']").click();
```

Answer (score 5):

```
jQuery('div[id^="user_"]').click();
```

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Answer (score 3):

```
$("div[id^=user_]")​​​​​​​​​​​​​​.click();
```

You can paste that inside the Firebug console or just put it in your page as it is valid JavaScript either way.

**[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/8gGUY/)**

Answer (score 2):

Selecting all elements with an attribute starting with some string:

```
$('div[id^="user_"]')
```

"Clicking" them:

```
$('div[id^="user_"]').click();
```

However, you might want to add a class to them, which beats string matching on attributes.